# Convert unknown shapefile unit to latitude and longitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have a shapefile that I don't know what is the unit of it. I always [used this useful site](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-latlong) to convert it to latitude and longitude unit but this site doesn't work since some days ago. 
I don't know anything about shapefile or geo coordinate systems I just want to have the shapefile with latitude and longitude degree unit. 
[Here is my shapefile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V_gV0Yel1fkgcH6b0aTvl850tkMU4JaS)

Comment: @BERA I have arc map, I added this shapefile and export it as new shapefile but it is not helpful.

Comment: Are you saying that ArcMap is not recognizing what coordinate system the shapefile is in? If it is then use [Project](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) to change into lat long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Project tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm):
Projects spatial data from one coordinate system to another.